# How to set default custom ringtone to a specific contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a list of contacts with custom ringtones and I need to reset the ringtones of specific contacts back to default.

As mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#CUSTOM_RINGTONE), when setting CUSTOM_RINGTONE URI: "If null or missing, the default ringtone is used."
Since "put" wouldn't accept null, i passed empty string ("") as shown in the code below, it runs and seems to be OK (if I go to that contact, it shows "default" on the Ringtones field).

However when that contact calls, the phone app crash!

(If I go to that contact and manually set default, again - no crash...)

How to set the ringtones field to "null or missing" ?

```
 private void ResetContactRingTone(String idOfContact) {
     try {

        Uri contactData = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String contactId = contactData.getLastPathSegment();
        Uri localUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, idOfContact);
        ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
        localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
        localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, ""); // <<----ho to set here "null or missing"?
        getContentResolver().update(localUri, localContentValues, null, null);
     }catch (Exception ex) {
         Log.e(TAG, "ResetContactRingTone failed, Excpetion: " + ex.getMessage());
     }          
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution:

replace this

`localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, "");`

with this

`localContentValues.putNull(ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE);`

and it works!